# Efficient way to recalculate/reflow a grid of absolutely positioned elements

Tags: javascript, dom

## Problem Statement

I have a grid, the element corners may or may not align but all the edges touch so there are no gaps. There are also no overlaps. For example, it's possible to have something like this:

```
+----+-------+
|    |   B   |
|    +---+---+
| A  | C |   |
|    |---| D |
|    | E |   |
+----+---+---+
```

The grid is created via absolutely positioned elements. (I realize it may be easier to create such grid via a tree instead, where the parent node is the container forming a rectangle with neighboring element(s), but I think that may limit the ways in which I'd be able to resize elements - I'll explain later).

I want to be able to resize a single element and have neighboring elements recompute their dimensions such that they snap to the new element dimensions without leaving gaps. For example, let's assume we're resizing element `C`:

- If I resize left edge of C towards A, I want A to shrink horizontally. Since A shrinks, both B and E have to expand towards A to fill that void.
- If I resize bottom edge of C down, E should shrink, no other elements should be affected.
- If I resize right edge of C into D, D should shrink, E and C should grow into that void.
- If I resize top edge of C into B, B should shrink vertically and D should expand with C.

### Why Tree Structure Won't Work

Now, as mentioned before, I realize that nesting these elements inside container elements (a tree-like structure) would handle the above case much easier. The reason I'm thinking a tree structure won't work for me (in addition to the fact that I already have too much code relying on absolute positions) is that I don't want the following case's resizing be dependent on the underlying tree structure that happens to be underneath:

```
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |
+---+---+---+
```

With a tree, this example wouldn't work, as the middle tile resizing would resize elements that happen to share the same parent/container, even if they don't need to resize.

## Current Thoughts/Work

I'm trying to figure out how to compute which additional elements need to be resized in an efficient way for my absolute elements. I'm thinking of something along the following lines:

- After resize that grows the element in a given direction, take the corresponding edge and perform `document.elementsFromPoint()` along this edge in a binary search pattern from one corner to another until the element returned for the min point is the same as that for the max point for every sampled point (if they're not the same, sample a new point at the midpoint and continue doing so recursively). This set of elements will contain all the elements that the element has invaded as a result of it's resizing (so they need to be shrunk by the opposite edge)
- After a resize that shrinks the element, perform the same kind of binary edge traversal along the original edge (before the resize), but a couple pixels in the opposite direction from the resize (this should hit the elements that need to grow to fill the gap)
- For the main element, it will be either one or the other bullet above (shrinking or growing), but the next step now is finding "side-effects", if the edge of the neighboring element goes beyond the edge of the original element, the same kind of analysis must be performed along this extension. This in turn may cause new side-effects along the same edge if we have a brick-like pattern.

The search explained in first bullet would be something like this, and then I would check for side-effects after:

```
function binarySearch(min, max, resizedElement, otherCoord, vertical=false) {

    function getElement(x, y) {
        if (vertical) {
            let tmp = x;
            x = y;
            y = tmp;
        }
        // we know there will always be an element touching, so this
        // should only throw an error if we pass bad otherCoord
        return document.elementsFromPoint(x, y).filter(e => e !== resizedElement)[0];
    }

    let elements    = new Set(),
        startIndex  = min,
        startElement= getElement(min, otherCoord),
        stopIndex   = max,
        stopElement = getElement(max, otherCoord);

    if (startElement === stopElement) {
        elements.add(startElement);
    } else {
        let middle = Math.floor((stopIndex + startIndex)/2),
            left   = binarySearch(min, middle, resizedElement, otherCoord, vertical),
            right  = binarySearch(middle, max, resizedElement, otherCoord, vertical);
        elements   = new Set([...elements, ...left, ...right]);
    }

    return elements;
}
```

Am I over-complicating this? Is there a better approach? Is this doable via trees and I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: does the underlying structure of the grid change? e.g will element A always take up the height of B, C, and E? will element B always be the width of C and D? do you need the structure to be dynamic? is all that will change just the size of each element?

Comment: https://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/ seems quite nice, but probably not remotely what you are looking for.

Comment: @RicoKahler yes, it does change. Elements could split or merge in arbitrary ways, but they will always respect the "no gaps" and "no overlap" rules. The overall container will also always be rectangular.

Comment: @AdamK. Thanks, that is actually interesting, I'll look at their code to see if there is anything I can reuse there. Overall, however, they've picked a simpler approach of moving tiles out of the way so it wouldn't quite work for me. It's interesting, however, that they also decided to use absolute positions rather than going with seemingly more intuitive "float", perhaps I'm on the right track.

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov good luck

Comment: A tree model works great for naturally partitioning the rectangular space, but becomes limiting in some common scenarios of use. However, I'm not convinced that a non-tree model is practical from an engineering perspective because it does involve quite some nontrivial work to enforce the non-overlap property of the layout. I think that having more capabilities of modifying the tree will lead to a well behaved system.

Comment: For example, since we are mostly just talking about resizing here, if you resize borders in your tree to align things together like a grid, the system should provide an option to convert it into an actual grid (whose edge resize behavior would now become more well-defined and intuitive), and also show the extent of grids, in some suitably subtle way with the UI...And if you would in the future want to break it out of being in a grid to fit things more flexibly again, that grid will have to be converted back into a tree.

Comment: Perhaps instead of the grids explicitly getting marked as such, you can get away with just the ability to fuse edges. So in the example above, that user would want the ability to break a fused edge back up. Either way it would need to be visually clear what dragging an edge will actually do, and preferably, you should be able to see the resulting change in the layout prior to committing to applying that change.

Answer (score 1):

If the underlying structure doesn't change then you can probably solve your problem with a tree structure [css flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Flexbox is a *very* powerful layout tool that is native to modern browser engines. You use css to declare your layout using `display: flex;` among other simple css.

CSS trick's flexbox tutorial can explain it much better than I can so please refer to [this to understand what's going on](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). The code below is more of a demo.

**The idea is to alter the flexbox styles of the element. To resize the element, change the `flex-basis` using javascript.** I just have buttons below to show the proof of concept but ultimately, you want to use mouse events to resize the elements. You can divide the `event.clientX` by the container width (`container.clientWidth`) to get a percentage of where the mouse is relative to the container and use that value for a flexbasis.

In the demo below, I'm using one variable to that I use to keep track of the flexbasis of the element `.a` and `.a-complement`. When you click the buttons, the flexbasis updates for each element. They both start off at 50% 50% and the grow/shrink by 10% which each button press. This example could be expanded to encompass resizing all the elements using the same technique. They would all respect each other's sizes and they would all have no gaps etc.

Moral of the story: let the layout engine do the work for you! Don't use absolute positioning unless you really have to.

**To address the tree structure issues:** you could restructure the tree moving divs into other divs when needed. If this complicates things too much then unfortunately the browser may not have native support for your document structure.

But it might in the future...

If flexbox doesn't solve your issue then the more experimental [CSS GRID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) might, but note that CSS grid is only implemented in the lastest browser and no mobile browsers which might be okay given your target audience.

```js
let aBasis = 0.5;
const elementA = document.querySelector('.a');
const aComplement = document.querySelector('.a-complement');
document.querySelector('#left').addEventListener('click', () => {
  aBasis -= 0.1;
  elementA.style.flexBasis = (aBasis * 100) + '%';
  aComplement.style.flexBasis = ((1 - aBasis) * 100) + '%';
  console.log((aBasis * 100) + '%', ((1 - aBasis) * 100) + '%');
});

document.querySelector('#right').addEventListener('click', () => {
  aBasis += 0.1;
  elementA.style.flexBasis = (aBasis * 100) + '%';
  aComplement.style.flexBasis = ((1 - aBasis) * 100) + '%';
  console.log((aBasis * 100) + '%', ((1 - aBasis) * 100) + '%');
});
```

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.b {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.c {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.d {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.e {
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.h-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1;
}

.v-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  flex: 1
}

.example-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="h-container">
      <div class="a">
        <span>A</span>
      </div>
      <div class="a-complement v-container">
        <div class="b">
          <span>B</span>
        </div>
        <div class="h-container">
          <div class="v-container">
            <div class="c"><span>C</span></div>
            <div class="e"><span>E</span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="d"><span>D</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="left">move a to the left</button>
    <button id="right">move a to the right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first solution wouldn't work for me since the structure does change, as I mentioned in my comment. But the CSS Grid one does seem interesting approach to look into in the future. It does seem quite powerful, the only limitation seems to be that the template columns are predefined, meaning that I'd be limited to "snap-to-grid" type resizing. Definitely worth investigating though.